# Isit possible to get the x and z coordinates base on where the cursor is in Three.js

Tags: javascript, mobile, three.js, 3d, webgl

Currently i am working on a project to make an 3D art gallery in ThreeJS and im using pointerLockControls to position the camera to the user, so that when the user moves with the arrow keys the camera will follow and rotate accordingly to where the user is and where the cursor is pointing at.

Now the issue is, since it is a 3D art gallery i would like to allow mobile users to interact with the 3D art gallery by tapping on the plane geometry, since they do not have arrow keys.

The solution i can think of is upon the onTouch event fired of, i need to capture the x and z coordiante of the touch then i can input it as parameter into the camera, but i could not figure any way even reading through the threejs documents.

If my method of approaching this issue is wrong, do explain and show me the way as I am primarily more of a web developer than a 3D game developer.